# Emotion Recognition real time analysis API calls

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I wanted to know.
Using the sample app, in the info it says: 
" The exception to this is in the "EmotionsWithClientFaceDetect" mode, which performs face detection locally on the client computer using OpenCV, before submitting any images to Cognitive Services. By doing this, we can visualize the detected face immediately, and then update the emotions later once the API call returns. "
But when i'm running the sample app, API calls are made regardles if a face is in the screen or not, or am I getting this wrong ?

My goal is to create an app that runs 24 \ 7 live. It should make an API call just when a face is detected. Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [push request](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Samples-VideoFrameAnalysis/pull/4) to fix it.  Thank you for bringing it to the team's attention.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Do you have any asstimate when an update will come with this fixed ? I am asking because my freelance work basiclly depends on this fixed. I Tried using a seperate face detection just for detection but it is not really speed optimaized and It will be better for all if the detection will be preformed only by Microsoft's code. Thank you.

Comment: The change has been committed.  Please bear in mind that this is a sample app, so treat the code accordingly.

Comment: I am aware of that, thank you. Would it work without any updating or should I download the sample video analysis app again ?

Comment: Are you using git?  If so just do a git pull.  If you're downloading the .zip, you will need to redownload and rebuild.  This is a client fix.  Or maybe I misunderstood the question?

Comment: You understood it correctly, I'm a beginner that is why the question was very basic, thanks.

Comment: I have to say I doח't really understand something, you added an else if saying that if localfaces == null then still call the API. and in the else you added the code for not calling the API. When local faces == null, doesn't it mean no local faces were found ? so the code will never go to the else, what an I missing ?

Comment: If `localfaces` is null, it means OpenCV was not called.  If it's empty, that means it was called and no faces were found.